# How to get scroll function on multiple screens

Tags: python, kivy

I want to implement a scroll function into my app, but I'm not sure how to add this to multiple screens. I would like all the screens to have a scroll function, but every time I try, I am only able to add it to one screen. Is there a way that makes it possible to add a scroll function to every window by default.

Here is my code:

Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ColorProperty, NumericProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.metrics import dp

class KivyApp(App):
    pass


class OpenScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass

class RegisterWindow(Screen):
    def seller_true(self, instance, value):
        if value == True:
           pass 
        else:
            pass

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def move_to_trade_area(self):
        print("Moved")

class TradeWindow(Screen):
    pass

class CustomTextInput(TextInput):
    border_color = ColorProperty([0, 0, 0, 0])
    rect = ListProperty([0, 0, 0, 0])
    _foreground_color = ColorProperty([1, 1, 1, 1])
    lower_border_inactive_color = ColorProperty([.5, .5, .5, 1])

    def _on_textinput_focused(self, _, active):
        # if active:
        self.lower_border_inactive_color = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        self._foreground_color = [0, .5, .23, 1]
        self.border_color = [210/255, 210/255, 210/255, 1]
        Animation(
            d=.4, t='out_bounce',
            rect=[self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height]
            ).start(self)
        self.hint_text = 'Email address'

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

KivyApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    OpenScreen:
    RegisterWindow:
    LoginWindow:
    MainWindow:
    TradeWindow:


<OpenScreen>:
    name: 'open'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        padding: '10dp'
        spacing: '10dp'
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Schoolsale'
            color: 'black'
        RoundedButton:
            text: 'Login'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'login'
        RoundedButton:
            text: 'Register'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'register'

<LoginWindow>:
    name: 'login'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: 15, 15
            spacing: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: "User Login"
                color: 'black'
                font_size: "20sp"
            CustomTextInput:
                id: username
                hint_text: "Username"
            CustomTextInput:
                id: password
                password: True
                hint_text: "Password"
            RelativeLayout:
                RoundedButton:
                    text: "Login"
                    size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
                    pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.6}
            Label:
                id: login_wrong
                text: ""
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 0
            Button:
                text: "Forgot Password"
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else 0.5
                color: 240/255, 70/255, 60/255, 1
            Button:
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else 0.5
                color: 240/255, 70/255, 60/255, 1
                text: "Go to the Sign Up page"
                on_press: app.root.current = 'register'
                on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

<RegisterWindow>:
    name: 'register'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: 15, 15
            spacing: 20, 20
            Label:
                text: "Sign Up"
                color: 'black'
                font_size: "25sp"
            GridLayout:
                cols: 1
                Label:
                    text: "Are you going to sell your own products?"
                    color: 'black'
                    font_size: "17sp"
                    pos_hint: {'right_x' : 1}
                CheckBox:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgb: 0,0,0
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.center_x-8, self.center_y-8
                            size:[16,16]
                        Color:
                            rgb: (240/255, 240/255, 240/255)
                        Rectangle:
                            pos:self.center_x-7, self.center_y-7
                            size:[14,14]
                    on_active: root.seller_true(self, self.active)
            CustomTextInput:
                id: username
                hint_text: "Username"
            CustomTextInput:
                id: password
                password: True
                hint_text: "Password"
            RelativeLayout:
                RoundedButton:
                    text: "Login"
                    size_hint: 0.3, 0.5
                    pos_hint: {'center_x' : 0.5, 'center_y' : 0.6}
            Label:
                id: login_wrong
                text: ""
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.2
            padding: 10, 10
            spacing: 10, 0
            Button:
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0
                opacity: 1 if self.state == 'normal' else 0.5
                color: 240/255, 70/255, 60/255, 1
                text: "Go to the Login page"
                on_press: app.root.current = 'login'
                on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'

<TradeWindow>:
    name: 'trade'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (230/255, 230/255, 230/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Button:
            text: 'Go back to home'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'
            on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'

<MainWindow>:
    name: 'main'
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (230/255, 230/255, 230/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: '20dp'
        padding: '20dp'
        RoundedButton:
            id: button
            text: 'A - Click to see more'
            on_press: app.root.current = "trade"
            on_press: root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
        RoundedButton:
            id: button
            text: 'B - Click to see more'
            on_press: app.root.current = 'trade'
            on_press: root.manager.transition.direction =  'left'

<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0, 0, 0, 0)
    background_normal: ''
    color: (0, 0, 0, 1)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
            radius: [18]

<CustomTextInput@TextInput>:
    rect: [self.x - dp(10), self.y - dp(10), self.width + dp(20), self.height + dp(20)]

    canvas.after:
        Color
            rgba: self.border_color

        Line
            width: 1.5
            close: True
            rectangle: self.rect

        Color
            rgba: self.lower_border_inactive_color

        Line
            width: 1
            points: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.center_y - self.height/2

    backgraund_normal: ''
    background_active: ''
```

**Edit**

By scroll function, I mean, when the page gets too long, you should be able to scroll up and down.

[image: (Yellow arrow shows where the scroll function is]

Comment: Could you please be more specific ? What do you mean by *'scroll function'* ?

Comment: Hi, sorry about that. I meant that when the page gets too long, there is a bar on the side which you can drag to move up or down on the screen.

Comment: Did you try using [**`ScrollView`**](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html#module-kivy.uix.scrollview) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried using ScrollView, but I am unsure how to add the scroll view onto multiple screens. For example, How would I add it onto the MainWindow and the OpenScreen